# Smoothing data received from CoreLocation

Tags: objective-c, core-location, noise, smoothing

I'm trying to develop an app which allows you to walk around, and where you walked will be drawn on a map. I have this all working fine, but I'm finding that even with a reasonably accurate GPS location the points still jump around a bit. When drawn on a map this has the effect of creating a squiggly or zig-zag line.

I'm looking for suggestions/strategies on how to smooth the data, so that the line drawn on the map is more of a smooth best fit, rather than an accurate point to point drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *many* different types of smoothing algorithms you could apply to the data (for a few starting points, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing) Wikipedia article). The only way to know for sure which is/are suitable for your application is to implement and test them.

Simple or weighted moving averages are fairly common (taking the last *n* samples and averaging them), but have the problem of lagging behind the data. A common one for filtering signal noise is a high-pass filter, which attenuates small (noisy) movements while passing through larger ones. Apple has some code for this in their [AccelerometerGraph](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/) sample.

I'd suggest trying those out first as they're easy to implement, before looking at the move complex ones.